# Homebrew + Python on mac os x 10.8: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread importing mapnik

Tags: python, module, homebrew, mapnik

I have 2 pythons on my mac (10.8.3): The default, and 2.7 version from homebrew.

So far, I could install modules and use them with my brew python. I installed mapnik with `brew install mapnik` (mapnik-2.1.0) and it compiled correctly. But, if I open python and enter `import mapnik`, the following error comes and python exits:

```
>>> import mapnik
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

Mac os x also shows an error window, with the following content:

```
Process:         Python [60666]
Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.3 (2.7.3)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [60454]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-03-28 10:21:08.535 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.3 (12D78)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          128837 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           5
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   4
Anonymous UUID:                      567121E6-7BAC-335F-E3B0-DD24D1F9E6BA

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff94500d46 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff92afddf0 abort + 177
2   org.python.python               0x0000000105a77eaa Py_FatalError + 49
3   org.python.python               0x0000000105a76370 PyThreadState_Get + 28
4   org.python.python               0x0000000105a71f16 Py_InitModule4_64 + 58
5   libboost_python-mt.dylib        0x0000000104153288 boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)()) + 40
6   org.python.python               0x00000001029fa716 _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 150
7   org.python.python               0x00000001029fa428 import_submodule + 296
8   org.python.python               0x00000001029f9ff1 load_next + 268
9   org.python.python               0x00000001029f80fb PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 794
10  org.python.python               0x00000001029de9d3 builtin___import__ + 132
11  org.python.python               0x000000010296e335 PyObject_Call + 101
12  org.python.python               0x00000001029e8e10 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
13  org.python.python               0x00000001029e61b6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11727
14  org.python.python               0x00000001029e32bd PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638
15  org.python.python               0x00000001029e2c51 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
16  org.python.python               0x00000001029f6e58 PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 247
17  org.python.python               0x00000001029f99bf load_source_module + 1053
18  org.python.python               0x00000001029f9c7e load_package + 334
19  org.python.python               0x00000001029fa428 import_submodule + 296
20  org.python.python               0x00000001029f9ff1 load_next + 268
21  org.python.python               0x00000001029f80fb PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 794
22  org.python.python               0x00000001029de9d3 builtin___import__ + 132
23  org.python.python               0x000000010296e335 PyObject_Call + 101
24  org.python.python               0x00000001029e8e10 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 93
25  org.python.python               0x00000001029e61b6 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 11727
26  org.python.python               0x00000001029e32bd PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1638
27  org.python.python               0x00000001029e2c51 PyEval_EvalCode + 54
28  org.python.python               0x0000000102a01a2b run_mod + 53
29  org.python.python               0x0000000102a0184d PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 365
30  org.python.python               0x0000000102a01367 PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 188
31  org.python.python               0x0000000102a01218 PyRun_AnyFileExFlags + 60
32  org.python.python               0x0000000102a120b2 Py_Main + 3210
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff966bf7e1 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff5d29c2b0  rcx: 0x00007fff5d29c298  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000000000ecfa  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5d29c2c0  rsp: 0x00007fff5d29c298
   r8: 0x00000000000003f5   r9: 0x00007fff5d29c270  r10: 0x00007fff94502342  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x00007fff5d29cb00  r13: 0x0000000102e9b656  r14: 0x00000000000003f5  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff94500d46  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x00007fff7bff7ff0
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
       0x102961000 -        0x102961fff +org.python.python (2.7.3 - 2.7.3) <62DA7BCA-2A0C-3753-A043-7459827F56D1> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x102964000 -        0x102a6cfff +org.python.python (2.7.3, [c] 2004-2012 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.3) <81E6FB4A-287C-37C3-A26D-D045B604933F> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x102c4c000 -        0x102c4efff +readline.so (0) <C4F1219C-CDFD-37D2-A762-22974D3F2918> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
       0x102c54000 -        0x102c77fff +libreadline.6.2.dylib (6.2) <2131C2A4-E75D-3680-9C8D-E42D78A5E1B9> /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib
       0x102cfc000 -        0x102d01fff +itertools.so (0) <F857A819-40A9-3F72-A0B1-3E97BA5F3DAA> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x102d0a000 -        0x102f2cfff +_mapnik.so (0) <433DAD47-AB4D-37C5-A0EA-FE1134B63D3D> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mapnik/_mapnik.so
       0x103603000 -        0x103978ff7 +libmapnik.dylib (0) <0E898678-9D86-35B4-A772-0248924F5BF3> /usr/local/Cellar/mapnik/2.1.0/lib/libmapnik.dylib
       0x104138000 -        0x104170ff7 +libboost_python-mt.dylib (0) <9B5DD680-BEC9-3988-9F55-F59DA38CC175> /usr/local/lib/libboost_python-mt.dylib
       0x1041b3000 -        0x1041c2ff7 +libboost_thread-mt.dylib (0) <24432300-9373-30B6-89F6-857CBEF9C105> /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
       0x1041de000 -        0x10424dff7 +libfreetype.6.dylib (0) <490EDE42-5B78-34BA-85E7-D0547BE778E1> /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
       0x104262000 -        0x104268fff +libltdl.7.dylib (0) <E437E59F-FC2E-3837-BDF8-301BEF13C7D6> /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
       0x10426c000 -        0x10428bff7 +libpng15.15.dylib (0) <52907DBF-A04C-325D-9E77-DF56A771026F> /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
       0x104293000 -        0x1042e6fff +libtiff.5.dylib (0) <AE85D7B1-F4E5-3B27-832D-5756EFCDE912> /usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
       0x1042f2000 -        0x104326fff +libproj.0.dylib (0) <C799D9A7-0DDA-334D-9AEA-13A4AE7A67A2> /usr/local/lib/libproj.0.dylib
       0x104333000 -        0x104441ff7 +libicuuc.50.1.dylib (0) <5FDBBF25-EEA6-3649-9ED6-B18CE89CE510> /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.50.1.dylib
       0x1044a3000 -        0x1044b2fff +libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib (0) <B2C03485-5FA6-3744-BC99-DB4E87DA4D87> /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
       0x1044c3000 -        0x1044c5ff7 +libboost_system-mt.dylib (0) <FE5E6E11-C7FB-3895-9976-526D22997EDC> /usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
       0x1044ca000 -        0x104578fff +libboost_regex-mt.dylib (0) <BC1D7F46-F6AB-3964-B344-E692EFC5D3B7> /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib
       0x10461c000 -        0x10464bff7 +libjpeg.8.dylib (0) <9EC07360-CF18-3529-AE54-E60DBF1313DC> /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
       0x104652000 -        0x105a24fff +libicudata.50.dylib (0) <B74D5789-7082-3084-9BF0-9A3AE6F2B046> /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.50.dylib
       0x105a26000 -        0x105b33fff  org.python.python (2.7.2 - 2.7.2) <E7F3EED1-E55D-32AF-9649-77C814693F6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
    0x7fff62561000 -     0x7fff6259593f  dyld (210.2.3) <36CAA36E-72BC-3E48-96D9-B96A2DF77730> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8ae57000 -     0x7fff8ae7cff7  libc++abi.dylib (26) <D86169F3-9F31-377A-9AF3-DB17142052E4> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff8c50f000 -     0x7fff8c510ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (220.2) <6838A6FD-8626-3356-BB4F-BB4787216207> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8c511000 -     0x7fff8c523ff7  libz.1.dylib (43) <2A1551E8-A272-3DE5-B692-955974FE1416> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff8d337000 -     0x7fff8d342fff  libsystem_notify.dylib (98.5) <C49275CC-835A-3207-AFBA-8C01374927B6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8d9e6000 -     0x7fff8d9ebfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (30) <08F8731D-5961-39F1-AD00-4590321D24A9> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff8dd72000 -     0x7fff8dd73fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (8) <8548E0DC-0D2F-30B6-B045-FE8A038E76D8> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff902d7000 -     0x7fff90326ff7  libcorecrypto.dylib (106.2) <CE0C29A3-C420-339B-ADAA-52F4683233CC> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff9064f000 -     0x7fff90650fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib (59) <D92DCBC3-541C-37BD-AADE-ACC75A0C59C8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff90a75000 -     0x7fff90a7dff7  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (379.37) <616FC901-151E-38BF-B2C4-24A351C5FAAD> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff914fd000 -     0x7fff9150afff  libbz2.1.0.dylib (29) <CE9785E8-B535-3504-B392-82F0064D9AF2> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff92899000 -     0x7fff928a7fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60027) <BAAFE0C9-BB86-3CA7-88C0-E3CBA98DA06F> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff92aa4000 -     0x7fff92b70ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (825.26) <4C9EB006-FE1F-3F8F-8074-DFD94CF2CE7B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff92bba000 -     0x7fff92bc0ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.1) <21703D36-2DAB-3D8B-8442-EAAB23C060D3> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff92ed3000 -     0x7fff92f3cfff  libstdc++.6.dylib (56) <EAA2B53E-EADE-39CF-A0EF-FB9D4940672A> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x7fff93019000 -     0x7fff93065ff7  libauto.dylib (185.1) <73CDC482-16E3-3FC7-9BB4-FBA2DA44DBC2> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff930cf000 -     0x7fff930d5fff  libmacho.dylib (829) <BF332AD9-E89F-387E-92A4-6E1AB74BD4D9> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff93177000 -     0x7fff93199ff7  libxpc.dylib (140.42) <BBE558BD-5E55-35E4-89ED-1AA6B056D05A> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff931f6000 -     0x7fff931f7ff7  libremovefile.dylib (23.2) <6763BC8E-18B8-3AD9-8FFA-B43713A7264F> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff931f8000 -     0x7fff93260ff7  libc++.1.dylib (65.1) <20E31B90-19B9-3C2A-A9EB-474E08F9FE05> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff9345d000 -     0x7fff9365dfff  libicucore.A.dylib (491.11.2) <FD6282D8-DF3F-3842-8C2E-CF478D2B9669> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff9365e000 -     0x7fff9365efff  libkeymgr.dylib (25) <CC9E3394-BE16-397F-926B-E579B60EE429> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff936d4000 -     0x7fff936dcfff  liblaunch.dylib (442.26.2) <2F71CAF8-6524-329E-AC56-C506658B4C0C> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff9424d000 -     0x7fff9427bff7  libsystem_m.dylib (3022.6) <B434BE5C-25AB-3EBD-BAA7-5304B34E3441> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff94284000 -     0x7fff94286fff  libquarantine.dylib (52) <4BE2E642-A14F-340A-B482-5BD2AEFD9C24> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff94381000 -     0x7fff94382ff7  libdnsinfo.dylib (453.19) <14202FFB-C3CA-3FCC-94B0-14611BF8692D> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
    0x7fff944ef000 -     0x7fff9450aff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2050.22.13) <5A961E2A-CFB8-362B-BC43-122704AEB047> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff94579000 -     0x7fff94587ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (77.10) <0D99F24E-56FE-380F-B81B-4A4C630EE587> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff94821000 -     0x7fff9493992f  libobjc.A.dylib (532.2) <90D31928-F48D-3E37-874F-220A51FD9E37> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff9493a000 -     0x7fff9494fff7  libdispatch.dylib (228.23) <D26996BF-FC57-39EB-8829-F63585561E09> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff95c25000 -     0x7fff95d22ff7  libxml2.2.dylib (22.3) <47B09CB2-C636-3024-8B55-6040F7829B4C> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff96350000 -     0x7fff96351ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (169.3) <9089D72D-E714-31E1-80C8-698A8E8B05AD> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff96397000 -     0x7fff9639cfff  libcache.dylib (57) <65187C6E-3FBF-3EB8-A1AA-389445E2984D> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff96646000 -     0x7fff9664dfff  libcopyfile.dylib (89) <876573D0-E907-3566-A108-577EAD1B6182> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff966bd000 -     0x7fff966c0ff7  libdyld.dylib (210.2.3) <F59367C9-C110-382B-A695-9035A6DD387E> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff96961000 -     0x7fff96963ff7  libunc.dylib (25) <92805328-CD36-34FF-9436-571AB0485072> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff974ba000 -     0x7fff974f0fff  libsystem_info.dylib (406.17) <4FFCA242-7F04-365F-87A6-D4EFB89503C1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff97850000 -     0x7fff97888fff  libncurses.5.4.dylib (37.3) <68D5B5F5-8252-3F1E-AFF1-C6AFE145DBC1> /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
    0x7fff978d3000 -     0x7fff97abdff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.8 - 744.18) <A60C3C9B-3764-3291-844C-C487ACF77C2C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 18730
    thread_create: 2
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=109.5M resident=53.3M(49%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=56.2M(51%)
Writable regions: Total=20.6M written=2644K(13%) resident=3256K(15%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=17.5M(85%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
MALLOC                             11.8M
MALLOC guard page                    32K
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
__DATA                             2356K
__LINKEDIT                         68.3M
__TEXT                             41.2M
__UNICODE                           544K
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             188.2M

Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6490M, AMD Radeon HD 6490M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334348302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.16)
Bluetooth: Version 4.1.3f3 11349, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: ST9500420AS, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0246, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Any problems with linking my pythons? how can I fix it? thanks!

Comment: Indeed, this error shows up when a module tries to use a python library that is different than the one the interpreter uses, that is, when you mix two different pythons. The list of Binary Images does show two occurrences of org.python.python: one by homebrew, and one in `/System/Library/...` To find out which library uses the latter, I would run `otool -L <dyld>` on each of the dynamic libraries in the list of Binary Images, and see which ones is linked to the system Python.

Comment: @Evert I'm having (basically) the same problem, except between my system python and MacPorts python.  The list of dynamic libraries in these error messages are pretty extensive... is there any easier way than using `otool` on each one?  Thanks

Comment: @Evert I'm having the same issue, can you please tell me what does <dyld> mean?

Comment: @zhermes I'm having the exact same problem as yours "system python and MacPorts python". How did you solve it please?

Comment: @AlexTwain `<dyld>` is just a placeholder name. Replace it by the full path name of each dynamic library in the list (i.e., the names ending in `.dylib`. The full path isn't given unfortunately, but finding that may quickly point you to the actual problem, as you'll notice the path is totally different than the Python you're using (for example, the `libboost_python-mt.dylib` listed above could be a system one, while the given Python is a homebrew one.)

Comment: @Evert I have a Macport python and I installed py-graph-tool which uses boost. How can I find the path please? Or at least guide me to lean how to find the paths in general. I'm so stuck for 2 days now :(

Comment: @Evert "Replace it by the full path name of each dynamic library in the list". Which list?

Comment: @AlexTwain `find /opt/local -name "libboost*"` should get you a long way. The list mentioned is the listing you get from the error messages. But if you have a similar problem but for a different setup (`py-graph-tool` and `macports` are not what is used above), you may want to ask a new question. Or use the macports mailing list, if you're doing it all through macports.

Comment: @Evert here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244642/macports-python-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get

Comment: @Evert I did `otool -L path_to_.dylib to every file in the list. But now when I try to import the library I got that it doesn't exist!!!

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you are running the homebrew python but either boost python or mapnik's python bindings ended up linking against the system python provided by apple. If a full clean and reinstall of boost and Mapnik does not fix this then I recommend stopping by #mapnik irc on freenode for help debugging. Generally to fix you need to call `otool -L` on `boost_python.dylib` and or on `site_packages/mapnik/_mapnik.so` to see which ended up with a linkage to the system python. Then you can fix by using `install_name_tool`.

Comment: yes, it's pretty werid...I found a thread of homebrew that apparently fixed this, but not for me https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16144#issuecomment-15799587

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem between python27-apple and python27 (installed by Macport). I tried these steps, and it worked for me.

According to @Evert's comments of different libraries used by different python, I tried to revert the python27-apple to be "active".

```
sudo port select --list python
```

For my computer, it showed:

```
Available versions for python:
none
python25-apple
python26
python26-apple
python27 (active)
python27-apple
```

in which python27(by Macport) was currently active. Then,

```
sudo port select python python27-apple
```

to make python27-apple active as the default lib were called previously. To double check,

```
sudo port select --list python
```

It now showed:

```
Available versions for python:
none
python25-apple
python26
python26-apple
python27
python27-apple (active)
```

And the python crash had gone when I ran the scripts.

Comment: There are a lot of situations where changing the active python cannot be done, for example, when you have installed a bunch of modules, or libraries in the macports python.
The solution for otmezger problem can only be resolved by using "install_name_tool" command line tool.
This thread gives information about using this tool https://developer.leapmotion.com/documentation/python/devguide/Project_Setup.html#supporting-32-and-64-bit-python-architectures

Answer (score 2):

I face the similar problem in using `androguard`. Though it's not quite the same, it can be a reference. My crash also is `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6`.     Run `otool -L <lib>`, suggest the `dylib` link to the system python.
Try solution:

1. `python-config --ldflags`
2. Copy the output to corresponding MakeFile. For example change `LDFLAGS += -lm -lbz2 -lz -llzma -lsnappy -lmuparser -lpython` to `LDFLAGS += -lm -lbz2 -lz -llzma -lsnappy -lmuparser -L/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation`.
3. `make clean`, then make again.

Now the dylib is OK, and no error anymore.

#### Alternatively ...

... when you use `otool -L <lib>` to find the wrongly linked python `dylib` you can use `install_name_tool` to change the symbol like:

```
 install_name_tool -change /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib  <lib>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the homebrew python like this:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 yourscript.py
```

Comment: As long as `/usr/bin/python2.7` is not symlinked to another interpreter. Which can be a case.