# module works for /usr/bin/python but not /opt/local/bin/python

Tags: python, macos, module, vtk

I've been struggling with installing the VTK package all day, and finally it looked like everything installed successfully.

When I `import vtk` I get the error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

That's using the default `env python` which points to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

If I use `/usr/bin/python`, which points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7/`
it seems to work fine!

**How can I get the vtk module to work for my default python?**

---

Why I want to use `/opt/local/` python instead of `/System/` python:
All of my other modules are installed via MacPorts for the `/opt/local/` python installation.  So if I use `/opt/local/bin/python` to import vtk, then I suddenly can't use `matplotlib`, `scipy` etc.

Why I can't install vtk with MacPorts:
I keep getting errors with the macports vtk installation --- I've submitted a trac error, but haven't heard anything yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu

Answer (score 3):

Was having this issue myself this week. The solution with thanks to [1] is to build it yourself from the git sources [2].

```
git clone https://github.com/Kitware/VTK.git VTK
mkdir VTK-build && cd VTK-build
ccmake ../VTK
```

- Press 't' for advanced mode. Ensure you've set "VTK_WRAP_PYTHON: ON".
- Press 'c' to run the first configure.
- Set PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /to/your/python (for Macports: /opt/local/bin/python)
- Set PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR: /to/your/Python.framework/Headers (for Macports: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers)
- Set PYTHON_LIBRARY: /to/your/Python.framework/libpythonx.x.dylib (for Macports: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib)
- Press 'c' to run final configure
- Press 'g' to generate make files

  ```
  make
  [sudo] make install
  ```

Depending on which OS X version you're running, keep in mind that they only support OS X 10.9 since VTK v6.10 which can be cloned from [2].

If you don't want to build it yourself and want it *all* through Macports, the following link may be useful, but I didn't try it: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/19569

[1] http://www.bioimagexd.net/wiki/index.php?title=Build_in_Mac_OSX#Building_VTK

[2] github[dot]com/Kitware/VTK