# Compiling shared library for python to distribute

Tags: python, macos, linker, swig, software-distribution

I'm compiling a SWIG wrapped C++ library into a python module, that should ideally be distributable for individuals to use the library transparently like a module. I'm building the library using cmake and swig on OSX 10.8.2 (System framework - Apple python2.7.2, Installed framework - python.org python 2.7.5)

The trouble I'm running into is that after linking with the framework, the compiled library is *very* selective of the version of python that is being run, even though `otool -L` shows that it is compiled with "compatability version 2.7.0". It appears that the different distributions have slightly different linker symbols and stuff starts to break

The most common problem is that it crashes the python kernel with a `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread` (according to: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu), indicative of a linking incompatability). I can get my library to work in the python it was compiled against.

Unfortunately this library is for use in a academic laboratory, with computers of all different ages and operating systems, many of them in permanent deprecation in order to run proprietary software that hasn't been updated in years, and I certainly don't have time to play I.T. and fix all of them, currently I've just been compiling against the version of python that comes with the latest Enthought distribution since most computers can get that in one way or another . A lot of the researchers I work with use some python IDE specific to their field that comes with an interpreter built in, but is not modifiable and not a Framework build (so I can't build against it), for the time being, they can run their experiment scripts in Enthought as a stop-gap, but its not ideal. Even when I link against the python.org distribution that is the same version as the built-in IDE python (2.7.2 I think, it even has the same damn release number), it still breaks the same way.

In any case, the question is, is there any way to link a SWIG wrapped python library so that it will run (at least on OSX) regardless of what interpreter is importing it (given certain minimum conditions, like guaranteed to be >=2.7.0).

**EDIT**

Compiling against canopy/python installed version with the following linker flags in cmake

`set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-L ~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_32bit/User/lib -ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython2.7 -u _PyMac_Error ~/Library/Enthought/C\
anopy_32bit/User/lib")`

This results in an @rpath symbol path when examining the linked library with `otool`, seems to work fine with enthought/canopy on other OSX systems, the `-lpython` seems to be optional, it adds an additional python symbol in the library reference to the osx python (not system python)

Compiling against system python with the following linker flags

`set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/config -ldl -framework CoreFoundation  -u _PyMac_Error /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/Python")`

Works in enthought and system python

Neither of these work with the bundled python with [psychopy](http://www.psychopy.org/), which is the target environment, compiling against the bundled python works with psychopy but no other python.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error/having the same problem. I'd be interested if you've found a solution.

I have found that if I compile against the native python include directory and run the native OS X python binary `/usr/bin/python` that it works just fine, always. Even when I compile against some other python library (like the one I find at `/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include` ) I can get the native OS X interpreter to work just fine.

I can't seem to get the Enthought version to work, ever. What directory are you compiling against for use with Enthought/Canopy?

There also seems to be some question of configuring SWIG at installation to know about a particular python library, but this might not be related: http://swig.10945.n7.nabble.com/SWIG-Installation-mac-osx-10-8-3-Message-w-o-attachments-td13183.html

Comment: edited for some additional information, I got the library working reliably with enthought and system python and just resolved myself to distributing a seperate library for users of psychopy