# pip install matplotlib fails on mavericks with homebrew

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, homebrew, osx-mavericks

I am trying to install the Scipy python stack, but having issues.
I have a new mac os with mavericks (10.9).
I have installed homebrew and am using brew to manage installations.

I used

```
% brew install python
```

then (I verified pip is from my homebrew installation)

```
% pip install numpy [this works]

% pip install scipy [this works]

% pip install matplotlib  OR pip install http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/matplotlib/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.3.1/matplotlib-1.3.1.tar.gz
```

Both fail with the same error.  After checking the backend, I get

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
```

The error message from mac os X (the pop up error window) shows errors very similar to those in the previous thread

[Homebrew + Python on mac os x 10.8: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread importing mapnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu)

It seems I need to fix the python bindings, as some of them linked against the `/System/Library` python that ships with the mac.  What is not clear to me from the above post is

1. which of the Binary Images need to be "re-linked"?  all of them?  some seem quite general an not related to `matplotlib`
2. how do I actually use `install_name_tool` to fix the link?  As I mentioned, some seem quite general - do I really want to change the path?  Do I `cp` the `dylib` from old to new?

I have also tried

```
brew uninstall python
```

and re-brewing, all to get the same error.  I am trying not to use `EPD` because `EPD` installs its own `libxml2` and others, which I need for other software I will install, and this has caused me problems on an old machine.  I am open to considering a `virtualenv`, but was hoping to learn to just fix my current problem if possible.

Thanks,

Andre

PS, when `pip install` matplotlib`, the following warning appears, which seems odd because matplotlib is such a staple piece of software

> You are installing an externally hosted file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing externally hosted files.
>
> You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.

Comment: Does typing `brew doctor` in the terminal produce any kind of warning? You may want to make sure that you're using the brew / pip python libraries rather than default system libraries by adjusting your PATH settings as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11076829/2942522

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention, that before all of this, I ran `brew doctor` first, which gives a clean bill of health, and also `brew update` just to be sure.  Also, I have set my PATH as described here [link](http://hackercodex.com/guide/mac-osx-mavericks-10.9-configuration/) so I have `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: looking through the python error report, I find the most suspicious dylib problems.  e.g. `Binary Images:
...
0x7fff8d613000 - 0x7fff8d781ff7 libBLAS.dylib (1094.5) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
...
`  there are many more, but BLAS and LAPACK libraries are needed for scipy and perhaps matplotlib, but I know they come with the new mavericks OS, so these are likely culprits.  Perhaps they are needed by /System/Library/...python as well, so how to use `install_name_tool` to fix them?

Answer (score 5):

This is an issue in pygtk. You can test it with brew (it should throw the same error):

```
brew test pygtk
```

I ran into the same problem, and got past that error with the following steps from https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/13654

- `brew rm py2cairo`
- `brew install py2cairo`

You can test that pygtk is working using `brew test pygtk` again.

I'm still having other problems getting `pip install matplotlib` to work, so you may also run into more problems, but that should get you past that particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and after some experimentation it seems that installing under Python 3 works more reliably. i.e. this installed without error:

```
pip3 install matplotlib
```

I then had to re-install everything else using `pip3`, and make sure I was running under python3 at execution time.

Answer (score -1):

```
brew install freetype
```

it works on mac os sierra!