# Cleaning out all other installed pythons on OS X

Tags: python, macos

For god's sake I'm going crazy. I'm on OS X mavericks. It seems that I installed a lot of pythons (Anaconda, EDA[something like that] ... ) and I just installed the one from Macports. Then also from Macports I installed a module for python called py-graph-tool. Now when I import this module in python I get this error:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread Abort trap: 6
```

I found [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu) the following: "this error shows up when a module tries to use a python library that is different than the one the interpreter uses, that is, when you mix two different pythons."

So I guess the solution would be to clean all other pythons. So my question is: how to clean all other pythons?

Comment: you shouldn't clean off the one that ships with OS X the OS uses it

Comment: You should use `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to use the Anaconda Python for scientific work...do the following:

1. create a file called `.bashrc` in your home directory (`~`)
2. add the following to it: `export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH`
3. close out all open terminals

Now when you open a fresh terminal, `python` should bring up the Anaconda Python.