# How to do a clean reinstall with macports?

Tags: python, macos, macports

How can one do a complete clean reinstall of a port and at the same time a complete clean reinstall of all its dependenceis?

Comment: Well this is odd. Just [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238497/cleaning-out-all-other-installed-pythons-on-os-x) minutes ago.

Answer (score 18):

From the MacPorts wiki (migration):

https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration

After having saved a list of installed ports using:

```
port -qv installed > myports.txt
```

and having removed them with:

```
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

Download and execute the restore_ports script. (If you installed MacPorts from source and used a custom prefix, then you'll need to use the `-p` option when you run `restore_ports.tcl`; see `./restore_ports.tcl -h`.)

```
curl -O https://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/contrib/restore_ports/restore_ports.tcl
chmod +x restore_ports.tcl
sudo ./restore_ports.tcl myports.txt
```

Comment: @KirkRoybal: That link is the definitive answer to this question, straight from the MacPorts people. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Save your currently installed ports

```
sudo port list installed | sed 's/ .*//' | sort | uniq > ports.lst
```

Then uninstall everything, leaving the structure in place

```
sudo port clean installed
sudo port -f uninstall installed
```

Then reinstall everything, with the new dependencies:

```
for package in $(<ports.lst); do sudo port install $package; done
```

Comment: This gives me *all* installed ports. Is there a way to list only the leaves of the dependency graph? For example, I wouldn't need to know of ports that will be installed as a dependency of another port.

Comment: Also wanted to point out that this approach doesn't keep the installed variants. Using `port -v installed` or somesuch instead of the `port list installed` would be better IMO.

Comment: What makes this answer better than the one by Marc?

Comment: @jvriesem well he's offering to download some script.. why doing this if you could show commands in here..

Comment: @holms: This is true, though the script is the script that the MacPorts developers recommend using. Presumably their script has more than just the commands in this answer for some reason. (One would hope! :-) ) Once nice thing about this answer is that it's transparent.

Comment: Any reason for `sudo` in front of `sudo port list`?