# Macports + Python on mac os x Mavericks: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

Tags: python, macos, macports

I installed python from Macports and also py-graph-tool. I'm getting this error when I try to import the module:

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

What to do please?

```
Process:         Python [23667]
Path:            /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:      Python
Version:         2.7.6 (2.7.6)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [23467]
Responsible:     Terminal [50142]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-03-07 08:57:24.172 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.2 (13C64)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  1B40C56A-15EC-7EF5-8BC6-31731287FB6A


Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called



Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x00007fff77b6c310  rcx: 0x00007fff5df95238  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000507  rsi: 0x0000000000000006  rbp: 0x00007fff5df95260  rsp: 0x00007fff5df95238
   r8: 0x0000000000000040   r9: 0x00007fff5df95200  r10: 0x0000000008000000  r11: 0x0000000000000206
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000104803a50  r14: 0x0000000000000006  r15: 0x00000000000003f5
  rip: 0x00007fff857e1866  rfl: 0x0000000000000206  cr2: 0x0000000109638d5c

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x02000148
Trap Number:     133


Binary Images:
       0x101c68000 -        0x101c69fff +org.python.python (2.7.6 - 2.7.6) <9EAA7EA7-0461-3548-A192-07D38564031C> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x101c72000 -        0x101d88ff7 +org.python.python (2.7.6, [c] 2004-2013 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.6) <980B2D89-E75B-3026-B8F3-CFFA635C4792> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
       0x10205d000 -        0x10205ffff +time.so (0) <7B313687-32FF-34C2-ACD8-C7A1790A3343> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
       0x102064000 -        0x102065fff +cStringIO.so (0) <EF9551C2-2514-3767-9447-9BA101184349> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
       0x10206a000 -        0x10206dff7 +_collections.so (0) <DDDAB77F-A531-3E13-BB63-240398C3E7C7> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
       0x102073000 -        0x102076fff +operator.so (0) <95D19C2D-417E-3A67-A1BB-97F6234BD4A4> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
       0x10207d000 -        0x102082ff7 +itertools.so (0) <A3DA6CBE-61F7-3D0D-9251-22F54CFA6CB8> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
       0x10208d000 -        0x10208efff +_heapq.so (0) <DB5A22ED-B9F3-39EF-A83B-8726F4F8A7E3> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
       0x102092000 -        0x102095fff +strop.so (0) <D4149B0D-D369-37B1-88AB-E54B00955B29> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
       0x1020da000 -        0x1020dbff7 +_functools.so (0) <B36EA2D6-B7DF-3592-93C3-0001BDFB4FEC> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.so
       0x1020df000 -        0x1020ebfff +datetime.so (0) <14C3C837-ACA0-3F99-9BF8-368E32EE6E24> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.so
       0x1021f7000 -        0x1021f9fff +_locale.so (0) <F6176B43-93D9-33D1-BD8A-E942B9C0BEF9> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
       0x1021fd000 -        0x102205fff +libintl.8.dylib (0) <569D1B6B-5EBD-3842-99E7-479B20BF4D1B> /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
       0x10220a000 -        0x1022fdff7 +libiconv.2.dylib (0) <103D57C8-BE15-3BF8-BDBE-53EDBDD0B6A4> /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
       0x10230a000 -        0x10230dff7 +_struct.so (0) <82587028-EEA5-3914-A170-AE64F1DE5B17> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
       0x102354000 -        0x102355fff +grp.so (0) <B1468245-66CD-364E-B04F-8A63C1A8BAE0> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/grp.so
       0x102358000 -        0x10235cfff +math.so (0) <7402006C-C00D-393A-9A6E-7240B2EFAAC4> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
       0x102363000 -        0x102366fff +binascii.so (0) <348F9879-1F59-35F6-9432-C30EB2FF50B9> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
       0x10236a000 -        0x102379ff7 +libz.1.dylib (0) <EE52BDB8-6083-3F10-A193-2E52AAF555E7> /opt/local/lib/libz.1.dylib
       0x10237d000 -        0x10237fff7 +_hashlib.so (0) <6125E492-1549-3D59-9779-E1BE90A89089> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
       0x102383000 -        0x1023c4fff +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <67018EB3-D462-3BF1-B162-1E3289178426> /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
       0x1023de000 -        0x1024f0fef +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <82BFA4EA-9D60-35E8-9EF8-4A684A8D3881> /opt/local/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
       0x102561000 -        0x102562ff7 +_random.so (0) <E3368733-211C-3892-AD8B-3F64FF7715BA> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
       0x102566000 -        0x102576fff +_io.so (0) <9CE31053-F63E-358B-9A65-C609C04AB8EB> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
       0x10258d000 -        0x10258efff +fcntl.so (0) <0FDB39F1-E6D6-3771-9FEE-E140DDA8DD49> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
       0x1025d1000 -        0x1025d4ff7 +select.so (0) <AEEEA7B4-CB06-350E-B1E3-B5D2C1364690> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
       0x1025da000 -        0x1025dbfff +resource.so (0) <4B0FBCA9-373C-3F1C-99BA-F8262DAE5208> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so
       0x1025de000 -        0x1025dffff +termios.so (0) <03DA0BEA-F344-3789-82FC-A8937E3BF14D> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/termios.so
       0x1027e4000 -        0x1027edfff +_sqlite3.so (0) <0FB3B379-B37A-3F3A-9F82-15658692577B> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so
       0x1027fa000 -        0x102888fff +libsqlite3.0.dylib (0) <FFAEAED6-2CD7-3D36-80D9-FC6946D4EBDB> /opt/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib
       0x10289e000 -        0x1028a6fff +_socket.so (0) <850E7950-CBBC-3025-AFA9-F2029122B52D> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so
       0x1028b2000 -        0x1028b6ff7 +_ssl.so (0) <0C2F22B0-D68A-346D-B96C-C28F99AAA41D> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so
       0x1028bc000 -        0x1028c9fff +cPickle.so (0) <2CD483B1-CE6C-3BE8-BD5F-B0A20F477DBD> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
       0x102911000 -        0x102915ff7 +_json.so (0) <3B7C233B-7EF3-386F-B903-5C61C89220FE> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_json.so
       0x10295a000 -        0x10295bff7 +_lsprof.so (0) <D5EECC6F-1AA7-34CF-BDB2-037E3389DF81> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_lsprof.so
       0x10299f000 -        0x1029affff +_ctypes.so (0) <2B4B6460-0913-3E02-AB47-B705EDA9D98B> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
       0x102e04000 -        0x102e37ff7 +readline.so (0) <D8A40BFD-FB97-3417-9D87-C93A41372D76> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline/readline.so
       0x102e51000 -        0x102e82ff7 +libncurses.5.dylib (0) <5FD4E3F4-FFC2-33EE-8F63-1F0F6C44BBEA> /opt/local/lib/libncurses.5.dylib
       0x102ed1000 -        0x102fbbfff +multiarray.so (0) <030DF069-55B2-31B4-A242-75A0E20C188E> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
       0x103061000 -        0x1030a6ff7 +umath.so (0) <4840927E-47BA-3354-AB5B-22BF4FCD4E1B> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/umath.so
       0x103112000 -        0x103116fff +_dotblas.so (0) <8F9FAB93-80F6-32F9-A406-89A6A06E8B19> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_dotblas.so
       0x10315a000 -        0x103176ff7 +scalarmath.so (0) <36D6FDF0-0B2A-316C-A655-5B8021B957F5> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/scalarmath.so
       0x103208000 -        0x10320cff7 +_compiled_base.so (0) <72B98C02-BC6F-32F2-B2FF-A875DF946BC0> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/_compiled_base.so
       0x103210000 -        0x103214fff +lapack_lite.so (0) <FAEA05CA-20B8-3FE2-8EB0-B3E76545EA42> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
       0x103218000 -        0x103225ff7 +_umath_linalg.so (0) <BEE109CC-BB44-393E-B04D-AAB0A1A9643D> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/_umath_linalg.so
       0x103271000 -        0x103271fff +future_builtins.so (0) <84110E0D-0171-3A3F-B660-70CE6B14442A> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/future_builtins.so
       0x103274000 -        0x10327cfff +fftpack_lite.so (0) <CF47109B-BC1E-3AEB-A324-EE416B40DA4A> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/fft/fftpack_lite.so
       0x103380000 -        0x1033b7ff7 +mtrand.so (0) <F09EE7AD-C5B9-3702-9FFB-A7768E164D18> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/random/mtrand.so
       0x103405000 -        0x10352ffe7 +_ufuncs.so (0) <C849E2C8-B236-369B-8EAA-7E6DA62B67D3> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs.so
       0x103593000 -        0x103655ff7 +libgfortran.3.dylib (0) <3DF49470-4342-38EA-BFAC-4ED0485E7941> /opt/local/lib/*/libgfortran.3.dylib
       0x10366d000 -        0x10367cfff +libgcc_s.1.dylib (0) <CB5989C5-40C1-3981-AAD9-749821C91651> /opt/local/lib/*/libgcc_s.1.dylib
       0x103681000 -        0x1036abfff +libquadmath.0.dylib (0) <56ABAFC4-2CC4-374E-9653-6953DBA9BD21> /opt/local/lib/*/libquadmath.0.dylib
       0x1036af000 -        0x1036befff +_ufuncs_cxx.so (0) <95AFA9E3-A9A9-3628-BBD6-F0A9360100A8> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/_ufuncs_cxx.so
       0x1036c9000 -        0x10378efef +specfun.so (0) <148ECDDB-B9C5-3158-9124-897CCDA2CA32> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/special/specfun.so
       0x10379f000 -        0x1037d0ff7 +_fblas.so (0) <04383174-F37C-3475-A7A7-F932DEDBBB1C> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_fblas.so
       0x103832000 -        0x10383dfff +_flinalg.so (0) <4FF07CFF-6172-377D-B66D-966E1BC72C08> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_flinalg.so
       0x103845000 -        0x1038a4fff +_flapack.so (0) <D6F77E6E-322E-3A73-BA6F-CAF0C621458D> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/_flapack.so
       0x1038e6000 -        0x1038edff7 +calc_lwork.so (0) <DD2F7868-CC98-3FD8-A9AE-FE1AF72FA136> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/linalg/calc_lwork.so
       0x1038f3000 -        0x1038f6fff +futil.so (0) <00314ED1-DEBF-38BC-9FF2-4FA34433507F> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/futil.so
       0x1039ba000 -        0x1039c0ff7 +minpack2.so (0) <5FF1DAD0-FE20-35E4-9458-B74E837BABC0> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack2.so
       0x1039c5000 -        0x1039e2fff +_lbfgsb.so (0) <DD0BCBCB-99B1-37CA-924D-2FB7BF34C703> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_lbfgsb.so
       0x1039e7000 -        0x1039edff7 +moduleTNC.so (0) <4820B6DE-8E71-36DF-8E6D-EF2F391A8F76> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/moduleTNC.so
       0x1039f0000 -        0x103a0bfff +_cobyla.so (0) <01955553-92B8-3EE8-8067-4C637036DA17> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_cobyla.so
       0x103a10000 -        0x103a29fff +_slsqp.so (0) <F58A5C29-13CD-32C3-9B30-D5C3A42ABB5B> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_slsqp.so
       0x103a2e000 -        0x103a4afef +_minpack.so (0) <3B3E0207-B017-3AA0-A507-5CB830D59003> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minpack.so
       0x103a8e000 -        0x103be5ff7 +_csr.so (0) <0ADDE689-D747-35EB-B360-50A6FAB7E3D4> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_csr.so
       0x103c34000 -        0x103d31ff7 +_csc.so (0) <C5841F58-99AB-3F9A-91EB-2BD465DBF007> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_csc.so
       0x103d6e000 -        0x103d9aff7 +_coo.so (0) <B9250078-BF24-3C94-A4BD-2667B03D3F52> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_coo.so
       0x103da1000 -        0x103daffff +_dia.so (0) <EF67E52F-5E07-383D-9093-E0C72035AD49> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_dia.so
       0x103db5000 -        0x103f66fff +_bsr.so (0) <CFC722AA-BE10-33B2-9BF2-1A22364ED188> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_bsr.so
       0x103fec000 -        0x103ff0fff +_csgraph.so (0) <78A2EAEE-4236-3DDF-ACE3-D25BB9944BEA> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/_csgraph.so
       0x104036000 -        0x104037ff7 +_bisect.so (0) <04B6B830-1DE2-3229-9744-99F1610129A4> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.so
       0x10403a000 -        0x10405cff7 +_shortest_path.so (0) <3AC605C1-3310-3586-93EB-DD95CC5587B5> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_shortest_path.so
       0x10406d000 -        0x104080ff7 +_tools.so (0) <9C2A84C5-3893-361B-AC42-0CB5D496F39A> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_tools.so
       0x10408f000 -        0x1040a1ff7 +_traversal.so (0) <FA496D31-9C4A-39B9-80F0-EE5E51ECF867> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_traversal.so
       0x1040af000 -        0x1040b8fff +_min_spanning_tree.so (0) <37D93F4C-1292-3337-BE1E-A18769E86741> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csgraph/_min_spanning_tree.so
       0x1040c1000 -        0x1040f1ff7 +_iterative.so (0) <331E4835-0901-3852-B1BF-44AF208AADAD> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.so
       0x104147000 -        0x104188ff7 +_superlu.so (0) <1E849C9F-F67C-3742-BCF4-21AB8B89E384> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/_superlu.so
       0x1041a4000 -        0x1041c0ff7 +__umfpack.so (0) <EA624B2E-4E42-36E1-B9FF-DA1F64128E6D> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/umfpack/__umfpack.so
       0x1041ca000 -        0x1043a5fff +libSuiteSparse.4.2.1.dylib (0) <731C7366-6C3F-35BB-BBF9-8B7FD33EC2A7> /opt/local/lib/libSuiteSparse.4.2.1.dylib
       0x1043c0000 -        0x104453fff +_arpack.so (0) <184584DC-D049-3854-B7FB-D1ECA346E826> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/linalg/eigen/arpack/_arpack.so
       0x1044ac000 -        0x1044adff7 +_zeros.so (0) <A7265B28-6C82-305A-BAA2-F663DA52E03C> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_zeros.so
       0x1044b1000 -        0x1044b8ff7 +_nnls.so (0) <7C98C9F4-6D92-353E-89E0-633D3555BEA9> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_nnls.so
       0x1044bc000 -        0x104505fef +_odepack.so (0) <F1235CFB-7DAF-3F77-8B12-24C1CC146393> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_odepack.so
       0x10450a000 -        0x104522ff7 +_quadpack.so (0) <37CB9FD2-69D6-3120-9904-1AC2C4F507D9> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack.so
       0x104526000 -        0x10455efff +vode.so (0) <3C056C6D-E352-3FCB-9457-46CFFBA6C5D2> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/vode.so
       0x104565000 -        0x104589fff +_dop.so (0) <C1A26ACE-163C-3FE3-89B0-BF01E064E0FE> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_dop.so
       0x10458f000 -        0x1045dbfe7 +lsoda.so (0) <6B3EE564-444F-35A4-BE7E-E0631E39D038> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/lsoda.so
       0x1045e2000 -        0x1045edfff +vonmises_cython.so (0) <68F6F17E-F856-305E-8019-92DEEEFAF3FB> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/vonmises_cython.so
       0x104678000 -        0x104685ff7 +_rank.so (0) <66BBB20B-781D-370E-8453-FE6660DA638B> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_rank.so
       0x104690000 -        0x10469cff7 +statlib.so (0) <45906AE5-59FA-3C6F-A92B-F68D543FE19A> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/statlib.so
       0x1046a2000 -        0x1046b1fff +mvn.so (0) <CB610F96-678C-31E1-832B-48E917631A22> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/mvn.so
       0x1047ee000 -        0x106825fff +libgraph_tool_core.so (0) <6E3739C8-4BB9-3E6C-8A09-1AF527459BB2> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graph_tool/libgraph_tool_core.so
       0x109324000 -        0x109330fff +libboost_iostreams.dylib (0) <50598239-332B-3A4C-BA01-94278B4CEFFA> /usr/local/lib/libboost_iostreams.dylib
       0x10934f000 -        0x10937fff6 +libboost_python.dylib (0) <FF611D0A-3AEE-3BBC-B5F2-5849658C8C86> /usr/local/lib/libboost_python.dylib
       0x1093c3000 -        0x109457fff +libboost_regex.dylib (0) <B81820A7-4B73-36BE-A092-46C40F1772B4> /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.dylib
       0x1094f8000 -        0x109513fff +libCGAL.10.dylib (0) <5E700CDE-B5A3-34C9-B26A-89D51D0D3BE8> /opt/local/lib/libCGAL.10.dylib
       0x109530000 -        0x109549ff7 +libexpat.1.dylib (0) <FC0B6E54-ED80-3460-B2AC-C8B5041957F3> /opt/local/lib/libexpat.1.dylib
       0x109550000 -        0x10955efff +libbz2.1.0.dylib (0) <57564CB0-AD8D-35AD-A8BE-EAF844A6005C> /opt/local/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
       0x109562000 -        0x10964cfff  libpython2.7.dylib (76) <0202C38E-0354-34FA-9996-8D2ADCE353D8> /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
       0x1096b2000 -        0x1096f7fff +libmpfr.4.dylib (0) <94D50580-60B2-3DB1-B273-1482CCE49204> /opt/local/lib/libmpfr.4.dylib
       0x109702000 -        0x10975ffc7 +libgmp.10.dylib (0) <98B78A55-7635-3C8E-8584-468AFBD4967A> /opt/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
       0x10976d000 -        0x10977affb +libboost_thread-mt.dylib (0) <57DDD8D7-9001-345B-91E4-E5ED3E7121EF> /opt/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib
       0x109798000 -        0x10979aff3 +libboost_system-mt.dylib (0) <D119E92C-749B-311B-90AB-4A070B60CDBE> /opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib
    0x7fff661bd000 -     0x7fff661f0817  dyld (239.4) <2B17750C-ED1B-3060-B64E-21897D08B28B> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff857cc000 -     0x7fff857e8ff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2422.90.20) <20E00C54-9222-359F-BD98-CB79ABED769A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff85977000 -     0x7fff8597cfff  libmacho.dylib (845) <1D2910DF-C036-3A82-A3FD-44FF73B5FF9B> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff85b33000 -     0x7fff85b35ff7  libquarantine.dylib (71) <7A1A2BCB-C03D-3A25-BFA4-3E569B2D2C38> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff86018000 -     0x7fff86019ff7  libsystem_blocks.dylib (63) <FB856CD1-2AEA-3907-8E9B-1E54B6827F82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x7fff86093000 -     0x7fff860c2fd2  libsystem_m.dylib (3047.16) <B7F0E2E4-2777-33FC-A787-D6430B630D54> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff86339000 -     0x7fff86339fff  com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.9 - vecLib 3.9) <F8D0CC77-98AC-3B58-9FE6-0C25421827B6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
    0x7fff8633a000 -     0x7fff86361ff7  libsystem_network.dylib (241.3) <8B1E1F1D-A5CC-3BAE-8B1E-ABC84337A364> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff86630000 -     0x7fff867e8ff3  libicucore.A.dylib (511.31) <167DDD0A-A935-31AF-B5B9-940268EC3A3C> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
    0x7fff87153000 -     0x7fff8717cff7  libc++abi.dylib (49.1) <21A807D3-6732-3455-B77F-743E9F916DF0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
    0x7fff878b8000 -     0x7fff87c99ffe  libLAPACK.dylib (1094.5) <7E7A9B8D-1638-3914-BAE0-663B69865986> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff87ca7000 -     0x7fff87cceffb  libsystem_info.dylib (449.1.3) <7D41A156-D285-3849-A2C3-C04ADE797D98> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x7fff87f17000 -     0x7fff87f28ff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (217.1.4) <655FB343-52CF-3E2F-B14D-BEBF5AAEF94D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff88dfd000 -     0x7fff88eadff7  libvMisc.dylib (423.32) <049C0735-1808-39B9-943F-76CB8021744F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff893fb000 -     0x7fff893fcffb  libremovefile.dylib (33) <3543F917-928E-3DB2-A2F4-7AB73B4970EF> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff8970d000 -     0x7fff89711ff7  libcache.dylib (62) <BDC1E65B-72A1-3DA3-A57C-B23159CAAD0B> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff89a80000 -     0x7fff89c2df27  libobjc.A.dylib (551.1) <AD7FD984-271E-30F4-A361-6B20319EC73B> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x7fff8a8ba000 -     0x7fff8a8d5ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (23.10.1) <A695B4E4-38E9-332E-A772-29D31E3F1385> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff8aa18000 -     0x7fff8aa22fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60049) <8C4F0CA0-389C-3EDC-B155-E62DD2187E1D> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8aa23000 -     0x7fff8aa24ff7  libSystem.B.dylib (1197.1.1) <BFC0DC97-46C6-3BE0-9983-54A98734897A> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff8b880000 -     0x7fff8b884ff7  libsystem_stats.dylib (93.90.3) <1A55AF8A-B6C4-3163-B557-3AD25DA643A8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8c1c0000 -     0x7fff8c1c7ff3  libcopyfile.dylib (103) <5A881779-D0D6-3029-B371-E3021C2DDA5E> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8c218000 -     0x7fff8c23cfff  libxpc.dylib (300.90.2) <AB40CD57-F454-3FD4-B415-63B3C0D5C624> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x7fff8c3f4000 -     0x7fff8c3f4fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.9 - Accelerate 1.9) <509BB27A-AE62-366D-86D8-0B06D217CF56> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff8cb7b000 -     0x7fff8cb84ff3  libsystem_notify.dylib (121) <52571EC3-6894-37E4-946E-064B021ED44E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x7fff8cf47000 -     0x7fff8cf4dff7  libsystem_platform.dylib (24.90.1) <3C3D3DA8-32B9-3243-98EC-D89B9A1670B3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8cf5d000 -     0x7fff8cf77fff  libdispatch.dylib (339.90.1) <F3CBFE1B-FCE8-3F33-A53D-9092AB382DBB> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8d0df000 -     0x7fff8d0ecff0  libbz2.1.0.dylib (29) <0B98AC35-B138-349C-8063-2B987A75D24C> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff8de44000 -     0x7fff8de45ff7  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4CDB0F7B-C0AF-3424-BC39-495696F0DB1E> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
    0x7fff8e279000 -     0x7fff8e54dfc7  com.apple.vImage (7.0 - 7.0) <D241DBFA-AC49-31E2-893D-EAAC31890C90> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff8e5a7000 -     0x7fff8e5affff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib (522.90.2) <A0B7CF19-D9F2-33D4-8107-A62184C9066E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x7fff8e6f7000 -     0x7fff8e6f9ff3  libsystem_configuration.dylib (596.13) <B51C8C22-C455-36AC-952D-A319B6545884> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff8e87e000 -     0x7fff8e8ccfff  libcorecrypto.dylib (161.1) <F3973C28-14B6-3006-BB2B-00DD7F09ABC7> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8e9c3000 -     0x7fff8e9caff8  liblaunch.dylib (842.90.1) <38D1AB2C-A476-385F-8EA8-7AB604CA1F89> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff8fd84000 -     0x7fff8fd8bfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib (35) <4CD916B2-1B17-362A-B403-EF24A1DAC141> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
    0x7fff90af3000 -     0x7fff90af8ff7  libunwind.dylib (35.3) <78DCC358-2FC1-302E-B395-0155B47CB547> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x7fff90ce9000 -     0x7fff90d3bfff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <4F68DFC5-2077-39A8-A449-CAC5FDEE7BDE> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff90d3e000 -     0x7fff90d41ff7  libdyld.dylib (239.4) <CF03004F-58E4-3BB6-B3FD-BE4E05F128A0> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x7fff90d42000 -     0x7fff90e0dfff  libvDSP.dylib (423.32) <3BF732BE-DDE0-38EB-8C54-E4E3C64F77A7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff91dd2000 -     0x7fff91fb7fff  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 855.14) <617B8A7B-FAB2-3271-A09B-C542E351C532> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff9202c000 -     0x7fff9206eff7  libauto.dylib (185.5) <F45C36E8-B606-3886-B5B1-B6745E757CA8> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff92082000 -     0x7fff921f0ff7  libBLAS.dylib (1094.5) <DE93A590-5FA5-32A2-A16C-5D7D7361769F> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff9228e000 -     0x7fff92295ff7  libsystem_pthread.dylib (53.1.4) <AB498556-B555-310E-9041-F67EC9E00E2C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff927d4000 -     0x7fff927d4ff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <3AA8D85D-CF00-3BD3-A5A0-E28E1A32A6D8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff92bff000 -     0x7fff92c88ff7  libsystem_c.dylib (997.90.3) <6FD3A400-4BB2-3B95-B90C-BE6E9D0D78FA> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff92e57000 -     0x7fff92e58fff  libunc.dylib (28) <62682455-1862-36FE-8A04-7A6B91256438> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff92e59000 -     0x7fff92e6aff7  libz.1.dylib (53) <42E0C8C6-CA38-3CA4-8619-D24ED5DD492E> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x7fff92f60000 -     0x7fff92f61ff7  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (278.11) <5E5A6E09-33A9-391A-AB34-E57D93BB1551> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
```

Comment: Alex, can you update your question with the list of dynamic libraries loaded by the macports Python. You can get that list by doing `otool -L /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`.

Comment: @Evert I'm getting this: ``otool: can't map file: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app (Invalid argument)``

Comment: Did you use the path up to `Python.app`, or did you use the full path as I suggested. From the error message, you seem to have missed `Contents/MacOS/Python`.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are not using the MacPorts python?
try
`port select --list python`
This should give you a listing of all you installed pythons. After one of them it says '(active)'.
This must not be 'python27-apple'.

If this is not the case, I have had similar trouble recently. See http://trac.macports.org/ticket/43086
Have you recently updated from an earlier version of OSX?
Have you updated your Xcode to the latest release and also installed the Xcode command line tools? And migrated MacPorts properly? See also http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration .
All this is necessary in order to link against the right c++ libraries, which graph-tool and boost are very sensitive to.

Best,

Thomas

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It's not a definite answer right. But it points the direction I would say. From the first two lines of the error report it looks like two different versions of python are called. I have had experience with a similar problem which was solved by making sure only one version of python is used.  Because I'm not 100% on this particular case I formulated my answer as suggestions...

Comment: As you are pretty new to SO I'd like to explain why I voites this answer to be deleted. It isn't an answer, because it almost exclusively contains a lot of questions. You should put these questions as comments and the OP will hopefully edit his or her question. Given you are provided with these clarifications you can then answer on a profound basis. This helps SO to be a useful Q&A ressource also in the future.