# Questions on Graph-Tool

Tags: python, boost, graph-tool

I am currently installing graph-tool-2.2. According to the description of installation, I first ran the Linux command line:

```
./configure
```

and it successfully configured. Then when I typed:

```
./make
```

it had already run for several hours, and seemed to be non-stopped at all. I am curious about how long it usually takes for "make", and how I can solve the problem.

Comment: There are other alternate methods on their website.why don't you try them

Comment: The command `./make` should have given you an error, as there shouldn't be a file called `make` in the current directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you need to compile from source ?
Because you may try to install a [Pre-compiled Packages](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/download) which is compatible with your current OS

You have to know before compiling that it could be a very long operation and especially when compiling "graph-tool" !

[thomasillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2747921/thomasillo) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947572/linker-trouble-with-macports-installation-of-graph-tool) :
**"Graph-tool was compiled anew (which took around 30 hours(!))"**

It is a very long process...

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think the main problem for compilation taking too long as my computer is with 2G RAM, so infinite times of page replacement causes running out of memory.

Answer (score 2):

It just takes a while to compile it. If it is indeed taking "several hours" this is perhaps because the compilation has run out of memory, and your system is swapping.

Comment: Thanks. it's very helpful! Now I know that the main reason is my Computer RAM is just 2GB, which is not suitable for compilation.

Comment: You would probably need slightly more than 4G. I would say around 4-6G, if you use GCC. With clang, you can compile it under 4G.