# Boost.Python python linkage error

Tags: python, macos, boost, anaconda

I'm running Mac OS X 10.8.4 (Darwin 12.4.0) with the lastest Boost distribution (1.55.0). I'm following the instructions [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/hello.html) to build the tutorial Boost-Python project included in my distribution, and it builds fine.

Nonetheless, the output compiled libraries depend on Mac's system Python and not the [anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) Python that I'm trying to link to:

```
[00:20] [tutorial] $ otool -L libboost_python.dylib
libboost_python.dylib:
    libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.18.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)

[00:20] [tutorial] $ otool -L /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib
/usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.2)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

I've tried the following configurations, but none of them seem to change which Python to use:

```
$BOOST_ROOT/bootstrap.sh --with-python=$ANACONDA_PATH/bin/python
```

or

```
# Here, I've explicitly chosen Anaconda-provided libpython2.7.dylib
# $BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib/libboost_python.dylib refers to the dynamic
# version of boost_python.
sudo g++ -I$BOOST_ROOT -I$ANACONDA_PATH/include -L$ANACONDA_PATH/lib
    -lpython2.7 $BOOST_ROOT/stage/lib/libboost_python.dylib
    hello.cpp -o hello_ext.so
```

or

```
$BOOST_ROOT/bjam python=$ANACONDA_PATH/bin/python
```

No matter what, I'll always get this message:

```
[01:58] [tutorial] $ python hello.py
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

Here's the system Python call in comparison:

```
[01:58] [tutorial] $ /usr/bin/python hello.py
hello, world
```

---

Similar: [Homebrew + Python on mac os x 10.8: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread importing mapnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu)

Answer (score 0):

After trying many other solutions I found on the web, I lost patience and decided to go with my own (very-bad) hack. I've created 2 bash scripts, one to link the sys's Python to Anaconda's, and one to relink back to the original Python:

`ana_py.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Link to Anaconda's Python
# $ANACONDA_PATH is the path to your anaconda folder

# BIN
cd /usr/bin

if [ ! -h python ]; then
    sudo mv python python_orig;
else
    sudo unlink python;
fi
sudo ln -s $ANACONDA_PATH/bin/python python

if [ ! -h python-config ]; then
    sudo mv python-config python-config_orig;
else
    sudo unlink python-config;
fi
sudo ln -s $ANACONDA_PATH/bin/python-config python-config

# INCLUDE
cd /usr/include

sudo unlink python2.7
sudo ln -s $ANACONDA_PATH/include/python2.7 python2.7

# LIB
cd /usr/lib

sudo unlink python2.7
sudo unlink libpython2.7.dylib
sudo ln -s $ANACONDA_PATH/lib/python2.7 python2.7
sudo ln -s $ANACONDA_PATH/lib/libpython2.7.dylib libpython2.7.dylib
```

`sys_py.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Link to Mac OSX Python

# BIN
cd /usr/bin

sudo unlink python
if [ -f python_orig ]; then
    sudo mv python_orig python;
else
    sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python python;
fi

sudo unlink python-config
if [ -f python-config_orig ]; then
    sudo mv python-config_orig python-config;
else
    sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config python-config;
fi

# INCLUDE
cd /usr/include

sudo unlink python2.7
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 python2.7

# LIB
cd /usr/lib

sudo unlink python2.7
sudo unlink libpython2.7.dylib
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7 python2.7
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python libpython2.7.dylib
```

Once you've run `ana_py.sh`, you can run `bootstrap.sh`, `b2`, & `bjam` without providing/modifying any of their Python parameters/options

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using `install-name-tool` to change the name of the dependent `dylib`:

1. To change the permission of your `libboost_python.dylib`:

   `chmod +w libboost_python.dylib`
2. Then change the dependent `dylib`:

   `install_name_tool -change libpython2.7.dylib /path/to/anaconda/lib/libpython2.7.dylib "libboost_python.dylib"`

Hope it is helpful.