# Error when running PyInstaller binary "Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, python-bindings

I am quite new to python and have question about pyinstaller

What I have:

1. Python script that imports dynamic library written in C++ (using boost python)
2. If I run this script using python everything works fine

   ```
   python main.py startup
   ```
3. If I create binary using pyinstaller, and then try to run it, I got the following

   ```
   dhcp80-241:bin gburanov$ ./my_binary startup
   Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
   Abort trap: 6
   ```
4. Backtrace of crash is following

   ```
   Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
   0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b997d46 __kill + 10
   1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff84074f83 abort + 177
   2   org.python.python               0x0000000108fe6eaa Py_FatalError + 49
   3   org.python.python               0x0000000108fe5370 PyThreadState_Get + 28
   4   org.python.python               0x0000000108fe0f16 Py_InitModule4_64 + 58
   5   idver_wrapper.so                0x0000000108f3cfb4 boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)()) + 36
   6   idver_wrapper.so                0x0000000108f29eeb initidver_wrapper + 27
   7   Python                          0x0000000108babe0d _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 183
   8   Python                          0x0000000108ba66a6 0x108b66000 + 263846
   9   Python                          0x0000000108b7f5a9 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9244
   10  Python                          0x0000000108b7d147 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1934
   11  Python                          0x0000000108bb6d7a 0x108b66000 + 331130
   ```

I have read that the problem can be that dynamic library is linked to one version of python and pyinstaller is linking to another version of python (mentioned here [Homebrew + Python on mac os x 10.8: Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread importing mapnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678153/homebrew-python-on-mac-os-x-10-8-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate-get-no-cu?rq=1) ) but I checked the following

```
     dhcp80-241:src gburanov$ otool -L ./idver_wrapper.so
     ./idver_wrapper.so:
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.2)
      /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
      /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

and pyinstaller log

```
    151 INFO: wrote /Users/gburanov/repo/..../build/my_binary.spec
    177 WARNING: You are running 64-bit Python: created binaries will only work on Mac OS X 10.6+.
    If you need 10.4-10.5 compatibility, run Python as a 32-bit binary with this command:

     VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes arch -i386 /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Therefore, I make the conclusion that pyinstaller and dynamic library python versions are the same.

Then, what can be the source of problem?

ADDED Later:
I looked closely at the crash report and notice that I still have two pythons in binary

```
Binary Images:
   0x108b0c000 -        0x108b28fff +sauth_binary (???) <9713FFC1-8C05-32D2-9F32-2D66A090EB52> /Users/USER/Downloads/sauth_binary
   0x108b66000 -        0x108c73fff +Python (60.4) <E7F3EED1-E55D-32AF-9649-77C814693F6A> /var/folders/*/Python
   0x108d89000 -        0x108d8cfff +_struct.so (60.4) <FF637943-8866-37F5-8B48-B97002F502A3> /var/folders/*/_struct.so
   0x108d92000 -        0x108d94fff +zlib.so (60.4) <9F2F691B-1510-335A-B9FE-6600523D90FB> /var/folders/*/zlib.so
   0x108eaa000 -        0x108eadfff +_collections.so (60.4) <02413565-C29E-3C7A-8E01-8C9C19642F15> /var/folders/*/_collections.so
   0x108eb3000 -        0x108eb6fff +operator.so (60.4) <FD5EC6F3-D0F9-358F-BF08-DC4B4F2109CB> /var/folders/*/operator.so
   0x108ebc000 -        0x108ec2fff +itertools.so (60.4) <36330819-32C7-3183-B213-2E1142050B3B> /var/folders/*/itertools.so
   0x108ecb000 -        0x108ecbfff +_bisect.so (60.4) <EE97CCA4-3D48-3CEC-B163-37E3AC0DCDA1> /var/folders/*/_bisect.so
   0x108ecf000 -        0x108ed0fff +_heapq.so (60.4) <7B91BA4D-5485-31BA-9FF9-789C6F3D0820> /var/folders/*/_heapq.so
   0x108f15000 -        0x108f18fff +strop.so (60.4) <282D8F1C-D709-339B-86E2-CE318F0E28E6> /var/folders/*/strop.so
   0x108f1e000 -        0x108f1ffff +_functools.so (60.4) <4DF8234E-F5DF-315B-A1CA-7C8C5C203901> /var/folders/*/_functools.so
   0x108f23000 -        0x108f24fff +_locale.so (60.4) <F8B95D0E-DAE2-359E-8B79-E3C8BE477D2D> /var/folders/*/_locale.so
   0x108f28000 -        0x108f60ff7 +idver_wrapper.so (0) <9EAC31C1-AE3B-33BA-B104-B80A7CD0FC14> /var/folders/*/idver_wrapper.so
   0x108f95000 -        0x1090a2fff  org.python.python (2.7.2 - 2.7.2) <E7F3EED1-E55D-32AF-9649-77C814693F6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
```

But the second one is in temp directory /var/folders and binary equals to /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python